# flowplayer won't play after update

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I'm building a site and I have it setup now to update the flv path on click of a link on the site. But when the link is clicked, it does the update of the url, but it doesn't play. I just get a white box.

Here's the code I'm using on the home page. It does immediately begin buffering and playing the first of 4 videos (which are stored as full url paths in a javascript array)

```
var player = flowplayer("container0",{
src: "/js/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
wmode: 'opaque',
debug: true
},{
clip:{
    autoPlay: true,
    scaling: "fit",
    bufferLength: 4,
    onUpdate: function(data) {
        this.unload();
        console.log(data);
        player.play();
    },
    url: videolist[0]
}});
```

Then, in my site, there are some links that run the following code:

```
player.getClip(0).update({ url:videolist[f] });
```

Where "f" is the index of the javascript array of video urls.

I know the update is happening because the console log shows an object when the update happens. But still it doesn't happen. I'd love some ideas.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with your code with some minor modification.

I create a  with onclick to a javascript function to update the url of the player as you did.
If the player haven't started playing (I set the autoPlay to false), and I clicked the link, then the player will successfully switch to the new video that I want it to play.
But if the first video is playing, then after the clicking, the player will be reloaded but it will still play the first video.

While above way definitely will not satisfy your requirement, I believe another way would be helpful.
Instead of call the update method on the clip itself, you can directly call the player.play(url:videolist[f]). By doing this, the player will play whatever video you passed in without the need to update the clip.

Below is my code snippet:

```
<html>    
<head><title>Video</title><script src="/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<a id="player"></a>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:update()">Update</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function update() {
    $f('player').play("SECONDVIDEO");
}
flowplayer("player", "/flowplayer/flowplayer.unlimited-3.2.8-dev.swf",
{
    clip: {
        autoPlay: true,
        url: "FIRSTVIDEO"
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that just might do it. I'll try it and let you know.